# Using SSIS Project Parameters in SQL Agent Jobs

Tags: ssms, ssis, sql-server-2019

I'm using SQL Server 2019 and attempting to set up project parameters for my SSIS projects. I've set up project-level parameters within the package itself and those parameters do appear in SSMS for me to configure:

[image]

I'm using multiple environment references which leads to a problem when setting up the new job:

[image]

As you can see, there's only support for a single environment, and it's requiring me to map the parameters again despite being set at the project level. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. I'm using SSMS 18.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as you say, you can only have one Environment reference in an SSIS project - which is a pity.

Your options are

1. Make a single Environment that all projects use for their configurations. Upside is that it's all in a single place and gets you past the problem you're experiencing. Downside is that all the cookies are in a single jar which probably isn't that great of a security risk. A more probable problem is organizational communication. Folder A/Project 1 has a connection string for OutputFile to C:\ssisdata\foo\bar\myfile.txt.  Folder B/Project 2 is deployed and they set up a connection string for OutputFile to C:\ssisdata\bar\blee\out.csv not realizing or caring that they've clobbered the setting for Project 1. Ooops
2. Each Folder has its own Environment. Upside is that again, you have all the configs is a single place and you're isolated from other teams potentially stomping on your settings. Downside is that there's more administration involved. Did the credentials for the Sales service account get changed? Now you have to update N Environments to reflect this
3. A hybrid approach. Use the richest Environment, like your SalesforceProd and then do direct configuration for the rest of the project elements. The good news is that this is a one-time task per project. Subsequent project deployments won't reset the configurations. Downside is the same as #2 in that you need to update configurations but now across each project when a "shared" value is changed.

And for what it's worth, there's likely no need to create explicit parameters for connection strings as you can click the "Connection Managers" section in the first screenshot and configure them from that screen. This allows you to trim out some extra logic/expressions in your packages and potentially avoid leaking sensitive data in logs or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with the #1 approach since we're a fairly small team and can easily communicate changes. Shame it wasn't just something I was missing and is intentional!